# UIButton subview of UITableViewCell unselecting UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a subview within UITableViewCell's that contains a UILabel and a UIButton. When I push the button it unselects the UITableViewCell for some reason.

Is there a way to pass the touch event through to its super view? Or is there a different problem all together?

Here is the code for CellForRowAtIndexPath. I plan on creating a custom subclass of UITableViewCell so I can handle cell reuse properly so don't feel the need to mention that.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CountModel *cellModel = self.viewModel.data[indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"RootViewControllerMetricCell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellModel.title;

    // Custom background color for selection
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xF3F3F3);
    bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    // Construct subview and append to bottom (only visible when selected)
    UIView *cellSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 125, cell.frame.size.width, 25)];

    // UILabel for display of current count
    UILabel *lblCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 25, 25)];
    lblCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [cellModel.count intValue]];

    // Create UIButton for incrementing
    UIButton *incrementButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    incrementButton.frame = CGRectMake(45, 0, 25, 25);
    [incrementButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Enable touch event for button view
    [incrementButton addTarget:self action:@selector(countButtonTouchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [cellSubView addSubview:lblCount];
    [cellSubView addSubview:incrementButton];

    [cell addSubview:cellSubView];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: So you want to interact with the button without changing the selected/ unselected state of the cell?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you add the `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndePath:] setSelected:]` inside the function responding to the button press to reinstate the same selected/ deselected state.

UPDATE:

Shift the code inside the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` to another function, say `performActionOnSelectionOfCellAtIndexPath` and call `performActionOnSelectionOfCellAtIndexPath` from inside the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` with the `indexPath` and also call `performActionOnSelectionOfCellAtIndexPath` from the function responding to the button press.

Comment: Thanks but this is also not working. If it helps, the behavior when I select a cell is to increase the height of the cell, reveiling the subview that is positioned at the bottom of the cell. This subview contains the UIButton.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the answer was slightly different from what you suggested, but I think yours would have worked fine so I'm flagging it as the answer.  My answer was to put "    [self.myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];" within the button action.